# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - 4 out of 4 instances are impacted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have implemented authentication system by using oAuth 2.0 in python django and deployed by using AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
Around 100 active user daily.

**Problem :**
I'm getting the error message below in health section of Elastic Beanstalk console :

> 4 out of 4 instances are impacted. See instance health for details

Instance health goes from `Info/Ok` to `Warning/Degraded`

What should I do to resolve this issue?

I am new to AWS.

Comment: hi @Hrushikesh-Shinde, AWS community can be a decent place to ask your question.

Comment: I'm assuming you have this behind a load balancer.   If so, then a good place to start would be to go to the EC2 dashboard .  Click Load Balancers in the left panel.   Find your load balancer, click on it, then click on the monitoring tab.    That will give you some details if hosts are going healthy/unhealthy due to healthchecks, connection errors, etc.     That should at least give you a place to start looking for what is going on.